# How to remove time from DatePicker ui jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm working with a jquery ui datepicker with asp.net mvc and when the web page open, it show the date with the time (2014/10/16 00:00:00) in the textbox for the datepicker, but if I select a date in the textbox for the datepicker, it will only show the date. I don't want to see the time, what's wrong?

Thanks!

The property in the model is set like this

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Ressources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName="ErrorStartDateRequired")]
[Display(Name = "DateStarted", ResourceType = typeof(Ressources.Resources))]
public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
```

My date picker is set like this in my web page:

```
@section scripts{
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var anchor = document.getElementById('@Model.Anchor');
    anchor.scrollIntoView(true);

    var d = new Date(@Model.Project.DateStarted.Year, @Model.Project.DateStarted.Month, @Model.Project.DateStarted.Day);
    $("#datePickerStartDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        defaultDate: d
    });
});
```

}

and this is how the control is showed in the web page (cshtml)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.DateStarted, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.DateStarted, new { id = "datePickerStartDate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.DateStarted)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the asp.net syntax, But it seems to be the problem regarding the initial value you set in the Date Picker ... for say in the syntax above         `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.DateStarted, new { id = "datePickerStartDate",value="pawal" })` , it will display value as pawal regardless the setting of the datePIcker

Answer (score 41):

I finally found my answer. I added "{0:d}" on the view side.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.DateFinished, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.DateFinished, "{0:d}", new { id = "datePickerEndDate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.DateFinished)
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#datePickerStartDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        defaultDate: GetCurrentDate(),
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).blur().change();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used it.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.DOB, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Date of Birth", id = "datetimepicker", TextMode = "date", value = "1/11/1989", onkeyup = "return validateChar(this)", maxlength = "20", style = "width:175px;height:25px;" })

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            lang: 'en',
            timepicker: false,
            closeOnDateSelect: true,
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this way to avoid time with current date avoid var d to assign

```
<script>
        $("#datePickerStartDate").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                gotoCurrent: true,
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTML Input field with the attribute

```
<input type="date">
```

This will display the browsers DatePicker.